# Filter td elements in a tr out, that are not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, selector

I have a Datatable in asp.net that i want to modifiy. I select the `<tr>` rows of the Datatable with JQuery:

```
var rows = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)");
```

However, the `<tr>`elements have multiple `<td>`elements and some of them are marked as `display:none`. How can i get the `rows`-variable without those hidden cells?

The purpose of this is to check cells if they are different from each other and only one line for each difference should be displayed. If i dont filter the not displayed elements, they get also compared and i have lines, which are visually the same.

**Update**
It works with just adding a CSS class to the `<td>`-elements that should be hidden. Then you have a clean DOM-Tree (i hope i can call it this way) in Firebug. The whole function below for reference:

```
function filterTable()

{       
        var rows = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)");
        var prevRow = null;
        var counter = 2;
        rows.each(function (index) {
            if (prevRow !== null) {
                var i = 1;
                var changes = 0;
                $(this).children("td:visible").each(function () {
                    if(i > 2){
                        if ($(':nth-child(' + i + ')', $(prevRow)).html() != $(this).html()) 
                        {
                            $(':nth-child(' + i + ')', $(prevRow)).css('backgroundColor', '#00FF00');
                            changes = changes + 1;    
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                });
                if(changes == 0)
                {
                    $(prevRow).css('display','none');
                    $(prevRow).removeClass();       
                }                 
                else
                {
                    $(prevRow).removeClass();       
                    if(counter % 2 == 0)
                        $(prevRow).addClass('dgItemStyle');
                    else
                        $(prevRow).addClass('dgAlternatingItemStyle');
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }


            }
            prevRow = this;
        });
    }
```

Comment: You want to get only those td which are not "display:none"?

Comment: Yes, i want to have the returning object without the child td's that are not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :not() filter for this.

If you have html like

```
<table id='tableid'>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td class="hidden">Hidden Cell</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="hidden">Hidden Cell</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td class="hidden">Hidden Cell</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Script:
If u want all the td elements in that table without hidden td elements then,

```
var rows = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0) td:not('.hidden')");
```

It would work!!

Comment: Isn't the use of the css-style selector (`:hidden` or `:visible`) better instead of a manually assigned class? those selectors keep track of any css-based way of hiding an element, including (but not limited to) manually assigned classes that hide an element.

Comment: I got the Script working, only with assigning the CSS class to the `<td>` elements that should be hidden. Then the DOM object doesnt display the other elements anymore. really wired. I just assigned the `.addClass("hidden")` function to the elements, and then select the table with the original
    `var rows = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)");`
And there you have no hidden elements in the object. Im wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var rows  =  $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)").find('td').not(':visible').remove();
```

Comment: that gets me more td's then bevor. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using jQuery.. So would

```
var rows = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)").not($("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)").has("td[display=none]"));
```

work?

Comment: No, it doesnt change the returning object at all. Im not very skilled in JQuery/Selectors, thats the reason why i came here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the td's that are visible, the following should suffice:

```
var visible_cells = $("#dgInformation tr:gt(0)").find("td:visible");
```

If you want the ones that are not visible, use `:hidden` instead :)

**Update**

I'm not sure what you mean by "How can i get the rows-variable without those hidden cells?".

If I read that correctly, you basically want the row, and have it's non-visible cells removed from the variable but kept in HTML.
This can't be done, as the variable you hold is still based on the actual HTML. The row-variable will not even contain any of the children. They will be looked up in the DOM when you request them specifically.

However, I assume at some later stage in your code, you actually get the selected row's `<td>` children. Apply the `:visible` filter on them whenever you need them,  **or** make a second variable which holds the children you want, like I suggested in my answer.

You just can't pre-emptively delete them from a variable without altering the HTML.

Comment: Then i get the td's as single objects without the tr's. i need them as the rows, but that is quite close.

Comment: If you have the `<tr>` you basically only have something that points toward the one(s) you selected. The variable does not contain any information about the children. Those are only retrieved once you actually request them.
It's important to note that using a selector does not copy the element's value, you only get a pointer to the element in the DOM.

Comment: The `<tr>` is neccessary for further row filtering. I did it with just adding a CSS class with the same attributes, but somehow i dont see the hidden `<td>`s now in Firebug and the filtering works fine.